# How to see built in member functions in visual studio 2019/2017

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering if there's a way to see what member functions are contained within whatever library you're using in VS. I usually just look them up online if I ever need to. I want to understand VS on a greater level. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your library should have an include file that you use to call its functions; that should be sufficient.

If you open that include file in the VS, the rightmost dropdown above the editor pain will have all available functions.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing the right dropdown, can you include a snippet?

Comment: @Brett - added a picture to my answer.